# Document.Protect(). Какие изменения привносит в файл?

Tags: php, c#, ms-word, phpword

На C# файл закрывается (открыть можно только на чтение) командой `Document.Protect()`.

Можно ли как-то определить, закрыт ли файл на PHP?

По-сути, `Document.Protect()` изменяет внутренние атрибуты файла, и с помощью PHPDOCX их можно прочитать и определить, закрыт ли файл или нет.
Но вот какие именно атрибуты надо читать - без понятия.